# Bootstrap 4 add additional table contextual class aliases

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I would like to add aliases for Bootstrap 4 [contextual table classses](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#contextual-classes)

```
<tr class="table-primary">...</tr>
<tr class="table-secondary">...</tr>
<tr class="table-success">...</tr>
<tr class="table-danger">...</tr>
<tr class="table-warning">...</tr>
<tr class="table-info">...</tr>
<tr class="table-light">...</tr>
<tr class="table-dark">...</tr>
```

For example,

- `table-size-xs` => `table-primary`
- `table-size-s` => `table-seconodary`

Is there a neat way to do this, or should I just use the define each class and set the background colour?

Comment: What are `table-size-xs` and `table-size-xs`? Do you mean the responsive table classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#breakpoint-specific. If you mean table sizing the only alt size is table-sm. Did you add new classes?

Comment: They are classes relating to the size of t-shirts. I can see how that could be confusing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the classes separately e.g.:

```
.table-size-xs {
     background-color: #123456;
}

.table-size-s {
     background-color: #654321;
}
```